# What is the better way of notifying my spring boot backend that an object has been stored into an AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, backend, bucket

I am currently trying to develop a "social media like" app as a personal project (to learn more)
I am currently designing the way my object storage will notify that an object has been successfully stored...

I can think of two ways of notifying my spring boot backend that my object was successfully stored into my bucket :

- Via the response of the request to the presigned link, the client notifies the success to the backend
- Via an AWS lambda function called once an object is stored that will request to my backend

I don't know what is better and would like to know more about the pros and cons of the two methods I proposed

Answer (score 1):

An Amazon S3 event can be triggered when an object is created in a bucket. It can:

- Send a message to an **Amazon SQS Queue** and your app could poll the queue, *or*
- Trigger an **AWS Lambda function**, which can run whatever code you want -- but the question then is how it will 'call' your backend, *or*
- Send a message to an **Amazon SNS Topic** which in turn can:

  - Call an **HTTP/S endpoint** (a good way of triggering a web app!)
  - And do other things not relevant for your use-case, such as send an **email** or an **SMS**

I'd recommend either **polling SQS** or receiving an **HTTP/S message**.